# Open JSON in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL server 2016 which has the Open JSON feature for importing the JSON files in to DB tables.

I have Json in below format with headers and values as the rows under the header same like in excel.

I have to create a Cell_State Table with header values as columns and **value** as rows.

Please advise.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
   "CELL_STATE" : {

      "header" : [
         "Node",
         "Logtime",
         "Cell",
         "Cell state",
         "SectorCarrier state",
         "SectorEquipmentFunction"
      ],

            "value" : [
               "LBI874",
               "2016-06-02 07:05",
               "L38741",
               "UNLOCKED, DISABLED",
               "SectorCarrier=1 DISABLED",
               "SectorEquipmentFunction=1 fqband=7"
            ]

              "value" : [
               "LBI874",
               "2016-06-02 07:05",
               "L38742",
               "UNLOCKED, DISABLED",
               "SectorCarrier=2 DISABLED",
               "SectorEquipmentFunction=2 fqband=7"
            ]
         } 

         }'

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$')
```

Comment: You could have checked its validity by pressing F12 in a browser and pasting your alleged JSON into the console.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON isn't valid, you're missing a comma after the first value block:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
   "CELL_STATE" : {

      "header" : [
         "Node",
         "Logtime",
         "Cell",
         "Cell state",
         "SectorCarrier state",
         "SectorEquipmentFunction"
      ],

            "value" : [
               "LBI874",
               "2016-06-02 07:05",
               "L38741",
               "UNLOCKED, DISABLED",
               "SectorCarrier=1 DISABLED",
               "SectorEquipmentFunction=1 fqband=7"
            ],

              "value" : [
               "LBI874",
               "2016-06-02 07:05",
               "L38742",
               "UNLOCKED, DISABLED",
               "SectorCarrier=2 DISABLED",
               "SectorEquipmentFunction=2 fqband=7"
            ]
         } 

         }'
```

Comment: Can you please advise on how can we store the values in database as requested.Thanks

Comment: I want to use the Open JSON in 2016 in order to store the data in to table with header as column names and Values as the values.Please advise..

Answer (score 0):

You JSON is invalid. You have missed a comma after 1st value block. Correct JSON is given below:

```
{
    "CELL_STATE": {

        "header": [
            "Node",
            "Logtime",
            "Cell",
            "Cell state",
            "SectorCarrier state",
            "SectorEquipmentFunction"
        ],

        "value": [
            "LBI874",
            "2016-06-02 07:05",
            "L38741",
            "UNLOCKED, DISABLED",
            "SectorCarrier=1 DISABLED",
            "SectorEquipmentFunction=1 fqband=7"
        ],

        "value": [
            "LBI874",
            "2016-06-02 07:05",
            "L38742",
            "UNLOCKED, DISABLED",
            "SectorCarrier=2 DISABLED",
            "SectorEquipmentFunction=2 fqband=7"
        ]
    }

}
```

This will resolve you issue.